# Mount AFP share from Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount

Looking to mount an AFP share on Xubuntu 16.04. On 14.04 I used afpfs-ng-utils, which worked beautifully, but it looks like it's not available for 16.04.

Is it reasonable to expect that afpfs-ng will become available for 16.04?

Is there an alternative to afpfs-ng? It seems like it shouldn't be a rare thing to want to mount AFP shares from an Ubuntu distro...is it really true that the only solution is one slow-to-update and maybe buggy independent project?